# Working of optoisolator MOC3041 & triac connection

Tags: triac, dimmer

1) Pl help me with the working of optoisolator MOC3041 & MOC3020.
   Also its use in ac dimmer apart from isolation

2) Also as triac(BT136) are bidirectional how does the term "reversed" connected gate of  triac come into picture?

3) what is MT & MT1 pin & its significance?

Thank you

Comment: Please link to the datasheet you are referring to. The one I found doesn't have an "MT" pin but it does have a "main terminal" pin.

Comment: http://www.soselectronic.hu/a_info/resource/d/moc304x.pdf

Comment: And where do you see a pin labelled "MT"?

Comment: its just pin where traic is connected. just take it as main terminal

Answer (score 1):

Here is the schematic:

[image: Triac with opto coupler]

MOC3021, MOC3041 and MOC3020 are all similar and can be used in the same way. Same goes for your triac.

Live is usually connected to MT2 (middle pin in BT136) and appliance is connected to MT2. I am not sure whether this is actually required. You should be able to get away with opposite connections as well.

The signal Triac1 comes from your micro controller.

Once you have made the project successfully, you will most like face these issues:

1) Triac not turning off in a few cases specially while driving fans.

2) Tubelights or bulbs connected to other triacs flickering momentarily during switching on/off fan.

3) Similar erratic behavior.

To get rid of these issues, you need to look into snubber design and it's application. You might need two snubbers - one for MOC and one for triac. A little costly but better way is to use snubberless triacs (BTB16-600 BW for example) and high dV/dt rated optocoupler (FOD420 for example).

Comment: What is significance of pin 4 & 6 as shown in schematic.Also what if i connect a gate in between 6 and  R12.will it alter the output, as triac are bidirectional

Comment: @GauravSingh - Go to the comment you posted which has the link to the data sheet. Go to the data sheet. Look at the right of the first page where it says "Schematic". Do you see some numbers, 1 through 6?

Comment: Gaurav - Do as @WhatRoughBeast says. Unless you get used to datasheets, it will be very difficult to do anything useful. You will end up wasting too much time relying on others to give you obvious information and if something goes wrong, you won't have any idea why. Get used to reading datasheets. Try to understand. If not able to then ask. For ex - pin functions and schematic are clearly given in the datasheet.

Comment: MOC3020 and MOC3041 have a common base structure, but consist of different components and have different behaviours. That is, you can make dimmer applications using 3020 since you can control the triac to be on at any point of the AC signal while you cannot do the same with 3041 since you can only turn its triac on or off at zero points of the AC signal thus makes it unsuitable for dimmer applications.